# Component field expansion of $(1,1)$ supersymmetric Polyakov action

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-gravity, sigma-models, superspace-formalism

I am working on the renormalizibility of two-dimensional nonlinear sigma models in string theory and particularly the $(1,1)$ supersymmetric extension of it. The following is based on the review by C. Callan and L. Thorlacius called "Sigma models and string theory" (link: https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/sigma.pdf). In the paper first the bosonic sigma model is discussed in detail, then in section 5.2 the supersymmetric $(1,1)$ sigma model is presented. My question regards the step between equations (5.9) and (5.10) on pages 61-62. I will introduce the necessary equations below but to state my question: I want to know how to find the nilpotent (or component field) expansion of a tensor that depends on a superfield (for example $G_{\mu\nu}(\Phi)$ below). I will explain this in more detail below after introducing the equations.

Equation (5.9) is the supersymmetric extension of the Polyakov (symmetric coupling) action. It reads after omitting the factor in front of the integral
$$
\int d^2\xi d\theta_+ d\theta_- G_{\mu\nu}(\Phi)D_+\Phi^{\mu}D_-\Phi^{\nu}.
$$
The quantities appearing are explained below. Equation (5.10) is the coordinate field expansion of this action after performing the $\theta$ integrals (again omitting the same factor):
$$
\int d^2\xi [G_{\mu\nu}(X)(\partial_+X^{\mu}\partial_-X^{\nu} + i\psi^{\mu}_-\nabla_+\psi_-^{\nu} + i\psi_+^{\mu}\nabla_-\psi_+^{\nu}) + \frac{1}{2}R_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}(X)\psi_+^{\mu}\psi_+^{\nu}\psi_-^{\lambda}\psi^{\sigma}_-] \\
= \int d^2\xi [G_{\mu\nu}(X)(\partial_+X^{\mu}\partial_-X^{\nu} + i\psi^{\mu}_-\partial_+\psi_-^{\nu} + i\psi_+^{\mu}\partial_-\psi_+^{\nu}) \\
- i G_{\mu\nu}(X)(\Gamma^{\nu}_{\lambda\sigma}(X_0)\partial_+X_0^{\lambda}\psi^{\mu}_-\psi^{\sigma}_- + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\lambda\sigma}(X_0)\partial_-X_0^{\lambda}\psi^{\mu}_+\psi^{\sigma}_+) + \frac{1}{2}R_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}(X)\psi_+^{\mu}\psi_+^{\nu}\psi_-^{\lambda}\psi^{\sigma}_-]
$$

The bosonic superfield appearing in these integrals has the following nilpotent expansion (equation (5.2)):
$$
\Phi^{\mu}(\xi,\theta) = X^{\mu}(\xi)-i\theta_-\psi_+^{\mu}(\xi)+i\theta_+\psi_-^{\mu}(\xi),
$$
where I have omitted the auxiliary fields because they do not play a role here. With this component field expansion of the superfield and the definition of the supercovariant derivatives given below it is not difficult to obtain the component field expansions for $D_{\pm}\Phi^{\mu}$:
$$
D_{\pm}\Phi^{\mu} = \pm\psi^{\mu}_{\pm} + \theta_{\mp}\partial_{\pm}X^{\mu} \pm i\theta_{\mp}\theta_{\pm}\partial_{\pm}\psi_{\mp}^{\mu}.
$$
With this one obtains
$$
D_+\Phi^{\mu}D_-\Phi^{\nu} = \theta_-\theta_+(\partial_+X^{\mu}\partial_-X^{\nu} + i\psi^{\mu}_-\partial_+\psi_-^{\nu} + i\psi_+^{\mu}\partial_-\psi_+^{\nu}) \\
 - \theta_-\partial_+X^{\mu}\psi^{\nu}_- - \theta_+\psi^{\mu}_+\partial_-X^{\nu} \\
- \psi^{\mu}_+\psi^{\nu}_-
$$
where I've ordered the equations such that the $\theta$ integrals are easy to do.

Now I would like to do the same thing for the $G_{\mu\nu}(\Phi)$ in the action and express it in terms of its component fields $X$ and $\psi$. Comparing the terms in the result (equation 5.10) I know the nilpotent expansion should be of the following form (I got this expression by guessing what it should be based on the result in 5.10):
$$
G_{\mu\nu}(\Phi) = G_{\mu\nu}(X) + i G_{\mu\lambda}(X)\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu\sigma}(X) \psi_+^{\sigma} \theta_- + iG_{\mu\lambda}(X)\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu\sigma} \psi_-^{\sigma}\theta_+ + \frac{1}{2}R_{\mu\lambda\sigma\nu} \psi_+^{\lambda}\psi_-^{\sigma}\theta_-\theta_+,
$$
I know the first term in this expansion ($G_{\mu\nu}(X)$) is correct because this gives precisely the first term in equation (5.10) after combining with the $\theta_-\theta_+$ expression in $D_+\Phi^{\mu}D_-\Phi^{\nu}$. The higher order terms should have this schematic form in order to combine with the remaining terms in $D_+\Phi^{\mu}D_-\Phi^{\nu}$ and give the desired expansion. I am however not completely sure about the indices and signs because I backward engineered it. The reason why these higher order terms need to be of this form is because we need a quartic fermion vertex with a curvature coupling, and we need the Christoffel symbols to form the covariant derivatives.

I am not sure how to find the correct coefficients for the $\theta$ and $\theta^2$ terms in this expansion for $G_{\mu\nu}(\Phi)$ by deriving them and I'm sure there has to be something I'm missing. I am expecting it to be closely related to Taylor expanding but I'm unfamiliar with this in superspace. It does seem possible to me that the Christoffel connection and curvature tensor pop up in this nilpotent expansion for $G_{\mu\nu}(\Phi)$ because these objects are build from first order and second order derivatives of $G_{\mu\nu}(X)$ so they should appear in this Taylor-like expansion. My hope is that someone can help me with finding this expression. My final chance would be to backward engineer this to get the right coefficients in the expansion, but this wouldn't help me in a different scenario.

- $\xi^a$ are the worldsheet coordinates
- $\theta_{\pm}$ are the Grassmann valued, anticommuting coordinates (the subscripts $+$ and $-$ denote flat $(+,-)$ signature lightcone coordinates)
- $G_{\mu\nu}$ is the target space manifold metric
- $\Phi(\xi,\theta)$ is the bosonic superfield in this theory
- $D_{\pm}$ is the supercovariant derivative defined as $D_{\pm}=i\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{\mp}} + \theta_{\mp}\partial_{\pm}$
- $a,b\dots$ indices denote two-dimensional worldsheet coordinates
- $\mu,\nu\dots$ indices denote ten-dimensional target space coordinates
- there are also spinor indices, but they are denoted by $+$ and $-$ explicitly
- $X^{\mu}$ are the bosonic fields and $X_0^{\mu}$ are the background fields that satisfy the classical Euler-Lagrange equations. However I don't think distinction between the two is important for my question.
- $\psi^{\mu}_{\pm}$ are two anticommuting Weyl spinors
- $R_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor of the target manifold
- The covariant derivative is $\nabla_{\pm}\psi^{\mu}_{\mp} = \partial_{\pm}\psi^{\mu}_{\mp} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\lambda\sigma}(X_0)\partial_{\pm}X_0^{\lambda}\psi^{\sigma}_{\mp}$

**Potential solution:**

Taylor expand as (ignore auxiliary fields)
$$
G_{\mu\nu}(\Phi) = G_{\mu\nu}(X) + \bar{\theta}\psi^{\lambda}\partial_{\lambda}G_{\mu\nu}(X) + \frac{1}{2} (\bar{\theta}\psi^{\sigma})(\bar{\theta}\psi^{\lambda})\partial_{\lambda}\partial_{\sigma}G_{\mu\nu}(X),
$$
where there are hidden spinor index contractions on the anticommuting quantities. They are contracted in the only possibile way.

I think this expression just so happens to be the nilpotent expansion I was looking for because you can use the Fierz identity for any three 2d Majorana spinors (which $\theta$ and $\psi$ both are):
$$
\psi_1(\bar{\psi_2}\psi_3) = -\frac{1}{2}\psi_3(\bar{\psi_2}\psi_1) - \frac{1}{2}\gamma^a\psi_3(\bar{\psi_2}\gamma_a\psi_1) - \frac{1}{2}\gamma_3\psi_3(\bar{\psi_2}\gamma_3\psi_1)
$$
to obtain something that does appear to have the right form. But I am still missing a factor of $i$ somewhere and I can't seem to get the Riemann tensor to pop out of these equations. Could someone help me with that final part? I know of course that the curvature tensor is formed from the Christoffel symbols, and the Christoffel symbols are yet again determined by first derivatives of the metric tensor. But just looking at these equations I don't see how to get the right expression.

Comment: You are missing the $F$ term in your expansion of the superfields in (5.2). Even though we eventually integrate it out in the end it should be there and it is necessary for getting the result you want to show